# Save Additional Order MetaData while processing payment

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, collection

How can I store additional Metadata and associate with an order while in my paymentcontroller ?

It's a custom payment gateway, and in redirectAction() , while calculating the hash, i would like to save api_key & hash_key with the order.

Here is the PaymentController

```
public function buildgatewayrequestAction(){
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
->getLastRealOrderId());
    $orderId = $order->getRealOrderId();
    $model = Mage::getSingleton('paymentmethod/standard');

            $gatewayhash_arg =  array(
                'TIMESTAMP' => gmdate("YmdHis",  time()),
                'amount' => $order->getTotalDue(),
                'api_key' => $model->getConfigData('paymentmethodapi_key'),
                'order_no' => $orderId,
            );
// Here i would like to save the $gatewayhash_arg['api_key'] with the
//current order so that It is accessible later
```

It just a metadata, I don't require it to be displayed either in backend or any frontend info block

I'll use it to check order status from the payment gateway if payment is pending after a particular amount of time ( opposite of ipn )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow code

```
public function buildgatewayrequestAction()
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
    $orderId = $order->getRealOrderId();
    $model = Mage::getSingleton('paypal/standard');

      $details =  array(
                'TIMESTAMP' => gmdate("YmdHis",  time()),
                'amount' => $order->getTotalDue(),
                'api_key' => $model->getConfigData('paymentmethodapi_key'),
                'order_no' => $orderId,
      );

      $payment = $order->getPayment();
      $payment->setAdditionalInformation(serialize($details));
      $payment->save();
}
```

**Note :** above data save in table  `sales_flat_order_payment` and field name `additional_information`

Comment: Luks like this is what I was looking for, assuming i can retrive this data using `getAdditionalInformation('field_name')` :)

Comment: Just : $additionalInformation = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation(); and $additionalInformation = unserialize($additionalInformation);

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit the `additional_data` field of payment entity associated to each order entity;

the `additional_data` value is a string so you have to serialize before saving and unserialize after loading.

```
// SAVING
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment $payment */
$payment = $order->getPayment();
// preserve already existing additional data
$additionalData = unserialize($payment->getAdditionalData());
if (!$additionalData) {
  $additionalData = array();
}
$additionalData['gatewayhash_arg_api_key'] = $gatewayhash_arg['api_key'];
$payment
  ->setAdditionalData(serialize(additionalData))
  ->save();

// LOADING
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment $payment */
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$additionalData = unserialize($payment->getAdditionalData());
if ($additionalData && array_key_exitst('gatewayhash_arg_api_key', $additionalData)) {
  $gatewayhash_arg_api_key = additionalData['gatewayhash_arg_api_key'];
}
```

Note: I did't tested the above code, hope it works as I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few of these answers and they did not work for me on Magento 1.9.2

I found that when I serialized and unserialized the data held in AdditionalInformation that the results would be empty.

Please bear in mind I am new to Magento!

This is what worked for me:

```
// Storing Initial Data in AdditionalInformation
$order =  Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($checkout_session->getLastRealOrderId()); // This may be different for you
$payment = $order->getPayment();

$data_to_store =  array(
    'Key_A' => $val_A,
    'Key_B' => $val_A
);
// error_log(print_r($data_to_store, true), 0);

$payment->setAdditionalInformation($data_to_store);
$payment->save();

// Somewhere else in code
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); // This may be different for you
$order_payment = $order->getPayment();
$additionalData = $order_payment->getAdditionalInformation();
// $additionalData var holds the data from AdditionalInformation 
// error_log(print_r($additionalData, true), 0);
$Data_Key_A = additionalData['Key_A'];
// $Data_Key_A var holds the value of Key_A from AdditionalInformation 
// error_log(print_r($Data_Key_A , true), 0);

$additionalData_update =  array(
    'Key_1' => $val_1,
    'Key_2' => $val_2
);

// Combine old AdditionalInformation with new Data
$additionalData_complete = array_merge($additionalData, $additionalData_update);
// error_log(print_r($additionalData_complete, true), 0);

// Store updated data in AdditionalInformation
$order_payment->setAdditionalInformation($additionalData_complete);
$order_payment->save();
```

I hope this helps!